# What type of database should I use to track which user has read which article

Tags: database

I am making a web application in which users can post and read articles. I want to show list of articles to a user (which is easy to do) but I want to show only those articles which a user has not read (the article gets marked as read when user opens it).

What type of database I should use to maintain such relationship considering that there could be 1000s of articles and 1000s of users. Considering the traditional `RDBMS`, say there are two separate tables, one for `user` (`user_id`) and another for `articles` (`article_id`),

1. I can't add `user_id`s against each `article_id` as an article could be ready by 100s or 1000s of users.
2. a user could have read 10s or 100s of articles. I can't add `article_id` for each user to keep track of which article a user has read

In my opinion, both the above approaches could slow/complicate the process of fetching articles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an RDBMS unless you have a reason not to.

> I can't add article_id for each user to keep track of which article a user has read

Yes, you absolutely can, and that's what you should do; a table like (pseudo-SQL)

```
CREATE TABLE user_read_articles (
  user_id,
  article_id
)
```

with an unique index over `(user_id, article_id)` is exactly the thing here.

You can also add extra data such as a timestamp for when the user read the article should you need to.

Comment: thanks. But then everytime I get an article from article table, I'll have to check in user_article table if the user has read this article. Wouldn't that be an overhead? Or is that an overhead I'll have to live with if I want such capability?

Comment: Well, the data needs to be somewhere, doesn't it? You can definitely do a join to get the information in one query, if that's what you're worried aboujt.